# UI framework used for QuickTimeX on Snow Leopard?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface

I'm wondering what kind of shenanigan framework or UI kit Apple used for the black QuickTime X windows.

Looking at the available options in Interface Builder, nothing seems to match.

Quicktime X

[image: Quicktime X]

IB options

[image]

It's kinda like a HUD (gradient top bar, dark) but it's darker than a HUD and has all the standard 3 buttons. It doens't look like a Textured Window either.

Can anyone shed some light on it? How could I create a Window like QuickTime X ?

(And also the controls within the window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Apple. They know how to do fancy stuff.

Go to Applications, find QuickTime Player.app, open context menu, choose "Show package contents" (or what it's called in English), Go to Contents / Resources and have a look at the images, especially titlebar-corner.png, titlebar-middle.png, … and close-active-color.png, …

Comment: Interesting, all the bar buttons (close, maximise) are in there too. So, would they custom draw the entire window?

Comment: As a side question, why do they go against their own design guidelines?

Comment: Why do you think they go against their own design guidelines? Which do you mean? Remember it's a multimedia app and not a business app. Besides that: remember to accept correct answers ;)

Comment: Ha! I'm aware of how SO works. it's the correct answer, so far.. I'll leave time for other people to answer. Re: guideline, well, they essentially went without all the available IB components, didn't particularly create a custom component and made it available for developers, and it looks nothing like the rest of the UI..